# not working "NODE_ENV=development nodemon server.js" commnd in window and showing error as below mention

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

NODE_ENV=development : The term 'NODE_ENV=development' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: This is because that command is a unix command. You need to type it on Linux or Mac OS or BSD etc. It looks like you are trying to run that on Windows in which case that is an invalid command. You can try running it on WSL though or something like gitbash

Answer (score 0):

Need `win-node-env` module

```
npm install -g win-node-env
```

For Windows

```
SET NODE_ENV=development
node app.js
```

Comment: all ready done but getting same response

Answer (score 0):

For setting environment variables like that on Windows you can use package called [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env).

You can install it by: `npm install --save-dev cross-env`. And then you have almost exact example from their docs:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config build/webpack.config.js"
  }
}
```